# How to a split string like this?

Tags: python, string, split

I would like to split a string like this:

"[41.298669629999999, -81.915329330000006] 6 2011-08-28 19:02:36 Work needs to fly by ... I'm so excited to see Spy Kids 4 with then love of my life"

into something like this:

[41.298669629999999, -81.915329330000006] [6 2011-08-28 19:02:36] [Work needs to fly by ... I'm so excited to see Spy Kids 4 with then love of my life]

Does anyone know how to do this? thanks.

Comment: Is the output 3 lists (of strings?)? Or 3 strings with `[]` around them?

Comment: What did you already try to do ?

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
r = re.compile("(\[.*\]) ([^A-Za-z]*) (.*)")
s = "[41.298669629999999, -81.915329330000006] 6 2011-08-28 19:02:36 Work needs to fly by ... I'm so excited to see Spy Kids 4 with then love of my life"
m = r.match(s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1) + " [" + m.group(2) + "] [" + m.group(3) + "]")
```

results in

[41.298669629999999, -81.915329330000006] [6 2011-08-28 19:02:36] [Work needs to fly by ... I'm so excited to see Spy Kids 4 with then love of my life]

The regular expression reads:

1. Find string between (and including) square brackets []
2. After a space, find anything which isn't A-Z or a-z
3. After a space, find everything until the end of the string

Once the three parts have been found it prints them (with square brackets around the 2/3 above). The exact regular expression you'll need will depend on what the exact rules are for how you want to split the string up - which you haven't specified in your question. Hopefully this will help you get started.